# Ansible - Change target to IP in task

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a role thats creates virtual machines & configures them. I need to perform a few tasks on the VM's before their DNS entries are created.

How can I get the task to connect to a known IP address instead of the usual ansible_host variable (FQDN)? I can't set it in the inventory file since the IP is not known when it is created.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The inventory file can use IP addresses.  See the jumper example in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set it in the inventory file as the IP address is not known when the inventory is created. I need some way to do it in the task, preferably in a manner that is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

The way you typically handle this is to use Ansible's [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/add_host_module.html) module, which lets you create inventory entries dynamically during your playbook run.  A task looks something like:

```
- name: add host to inventory
  add_host:
    name: my_new_host
    ansible_host: "{{ new_host_ipaddr }}"
    groups: [webservers]
```

You can see an example of this in action [here](http://blog.oddbit.com/2015/10/26/ansible-20-new-openstack-modules/) (just search for `add_host`).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that will help either as the host already exists in the inventory as an FQDN. I think I just need to override the ansible_host variable to be the IP address for the specific tasks. I've tried using set_fact and setting a task var to change it but neither seem to actually change the variable (confirmed via debug).

Comment: I think you can use `add_host` to modify an existing inventory entry, but I'm not positive.  Give it a shot.